# Getting error: Conversion from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date

If anyone can rewrite this for me I'd really appreciate it. I'm trying to change stored date if null. I've tried Me.vipEndDate ="0000-00-00" and much more.

```
            If DR("vipEndDate") Is Nothing Then
              Me.vipEndDate = "0"
            Else
              Me.vipEndDate = DR("vipEndDate").ToString
            End If
```

Comment: I've set it up in database as DATE not DATETIME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could add some error protection. The [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx) attempts to convert a string to a date, if it does not convert it returns false so you code will not execute with an error.

```
Dim dt As Date
If Date.TryParse(DR("vipEndDate").ToString, dt) Then
  'this part only executes if string convert
  Me.vipEndDate = dt
End If
```

Comment: Wow, that didn't throw any errors. Thanks. Not sure completely what it's doing, can you please explain ? Thanks again,

Comment: I like it ! Just starting out and doing well but this caught me out. Won't forget it. Thank you. You have no idea how much you've helped me out this end. :-)